# Error 'bool' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'

Tags: python

## This is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser
import time

def insta_log_in():
    driver=webbrowser.open('https://www.instagram.com')

    log_=driver.find_element_by_class_name('_0mzm- sqdOP yWX7d        ')
    log_bt.click()
insta_log_in()
```

## Run

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\instah.py", line 11, in <module>
    insta_log_in()
  File "C:\Python34\instah.py", line 8, in insta_log_in
    log_=driver.find_element_by_id('_0mzm- sqdOP yWX7d        ')
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'
```

and this is the error which I get. I am studying Python myself, so if anyone knows how to fix this error - please, help me to figure it out.

Comment: `webbrowser.open(...)` outputs only a boolean and you don't get it to find elements. For that use `webdriver`, like for example `webdriver.FireFox()`.

Comment: The `driver` variable is a bool (true or false) that is being returned by the `open` function to tell you whether it was successful or not. So, when you call `find_element_by_class_name` on `driver` it doesn't work. You are getting the error because `driver` is just a bool, it doesn't know how to `find_element_by_class_name`. Maybe think about what `webbrowser` can do now that it has opened a URL?

Comment: Read the [getting started tutorial](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) to find out how to use selenium properly.

Comment: Thank you very much but i can't use webdriver, i downloaded selenium but i have different problems, there is no way to do what i want without using webdriver?

Comment: @ScooterzGiovanni What problems? What are you trying to do? Please read: [ask].

Comment: So the only way to do that is using webdriver ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `webbrowser.open('https://www.instagram.com')` returns `bool` type therefor you can not call `find_element_by_id` on a bool python type.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webbrowser
import time

def insta_log_in():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
    log_=driver.find_element_by_class_name('_0mzm- sqdOP yWX7d        ')
    log_bt.click()
insta_log_in()
```

Comment: Without using webdriver?